# What's my error? How can I fix it?

Tags: java, gridworld

**UPDATE:** All I need answered is the question at the bottom.

This is a special type of `SpiralBug` so I haven't seen any examples of this on the internet. This `SpiralBug` uses the `SpiralBug` code but it has extras to it, once it gets to it's border of a `BoundedGrid` and cannot move forward anymore it has to restart at the center of the grid again, this is where my problems begin. Here is my code there are no errors.

My code for SpiralBugRunner

```
    import info.gridworld.actor.ActorWorld; 
    import info.gridworld.grid.Location; 
    import java.awt.Color; 

    public class SpiralBugRunner 
     { 
      public static void main( String args[] ) 
      { 
      ActorWorld world = new ActorWorld( ); 
      SpiralBug bug1 = new SpiralBug(0);

      world.add (new Location(4, 4), bug1 );

      world.show( ); 
      } 
     }
```

and for SpiralBug

```
import info.gridworld.actor.Bug;
import info.gridworld.actor.Actor;
import info.gridworld.grid.Location;

public class SpiralBug extends Bug 
 { 
  private int sideLength; 
  private int steps; 

  public SpiralBug(int n) 
  { 
    sideLength = n; 
    steps = 0; 
  }

  public void act() 
  { 
   if (steps < sideLength && canMove()) 
   { 
    move(); 
    steps++; 
   } 
    else 
   { 
    turn(); 
    turn(); 
    steps = 0; 
    sideLength++; 
   }  
  }

 public void moveTo(Location newLocation)
  {
   Location loc = new Location(getGrid().getNumCols(), getGrid().getNumRows());
   moveTo(loc);
   sideLength = 0;
  }
 }
```

**My real question is what should I do to set to reset the bug to the middle to run it again after it cannot move?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling this method within itself, causing a StackOverflow error.

```
public void moveTo(Location newLocation)
{
    Location loc = new Location(getGrid().getNumCols(), getGrid().getNumRows());
    moveTo(loc);
    sideLength = 0;
}
```

This is the wrong method. This should be in the `move()` method. The `moveTo` method takes a location and moves to that location. This should not be overriden.

Change it to:

```
public void move(Location newLocation)
{
    Location loc = new Location(getGrid().getNumCols(), getGrid().getNumRows());
    moveTo(loc);
    sideLength = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for attempting to answer my question, but this only helps my code not to have anymore errors. I now just have problems getting the bug in the middle of the grid after it cannot move forward anymore.

Comment: @PowerofMerlin that's a problem with what your code is trying to accomplish. Your question was "What's my error? How can I fix it?" and I answered that.

Comment: @PowerofMerlin if you want more help ask another question, or message me.